# Debian VPS : can't apt-get update

Tags: debian, package-management, apt-get, vps, aptitude

I have debian on a VPS and when I do "sudo apt-get update" it failed like this :

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.pm2.io/ubuntu/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'apt.pm2.io'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My source.list file :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
```

I read somewhere I need to replace some sourcelist link but can't find "apt.pm2" ?

Comment: I would check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pm2.list` and yes, you need to remove it, that repo is gone.

Answer (score 1):

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pm2.list

Did the fix